# Create multiple columns of values that are in second column and fill new data frame with number of occurences according to first column

Tags: r

I am new to stack overflow and sorry if I am not asking question properly.
I have two columns `country` and `Year`.

```
    INDIA 1970
    USA   1970
    USA   1971
    INDIA 1970
    .
    .
    UK    1972
```

I want new data frame like this and I need to fill it with occurrences.

```
            1970 1971 1972.... 
    INDIA    2
    USA      1     1
    UK                1
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: multiple ways to do this, simplest is `table(df)`

Answer (score 3):

An option could be to use `reshape2::dcast` with `fun.aggregate` argument set as `length`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Country~Year, length)
#   Country 1970 1971 1972
# 1   INDIA    2    0    0
# 2      UK    0    0    1
# 3     USA    1    1    0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Country Year
INDIA 1970
USA   1970
USA   1971
INDIA 1970
UK    1972",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```